# DefaultMessageListenerContainer does not stop

Tags: java, spring, jms

I'm using Spring JMS with the following context XML file.

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"
      p:brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" />

<bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" destroy-method="stop"
      p:connectionFactory-ref="connectionFactory" />

<bean id="queue1" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="foo.bar"/>
</bean>

<bean id="listenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer" destroy-method="destroy"
      p:autoStartup="true"
      p:connectionFactory-ref="pooledConnectionFactory"
      p:destination-ref="queue1"
      p:messageListener-ref="listener"
      p:acceptMessagesWhileStopping="false"
      p:sessionTransacted="true" />
```

My app is command-line standalone, and, looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException, InterruptedException  {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("my-context.xml");
    context.registerShutdownHook();

    App app = context.getBean("app", App.class);
    app.start();
}
```

The problem here is, when the main thread ended, the process does not stop. My current guess it that listener container is not stopping.

This is log messages at the end:

```
16:54:02,747 DEBUG [main] DefaultListableBeanFactory:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'app'
16:54:02,747  INFO [main] App:47 - Terminating...
16:54:02,747  INFO [main] App:51 - Terminated.
16:54:02,771 DEBUG [listenerContainer-1] TaskRunnerFactory:91 - Initialized TaskRunnerFactory[ActiveMQ Session Task] using ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@6c63a721
16:54:03,783 DEBUG [listenerContainer-1] ActiveMQSession:559 - ID:Daniels-MacBook-Pro.local-56179-1359680042616-1:1:1 Transaction Commit :null
16:54:04,784 DEBUG [listenerContainer-1] ActiveMQSession:559 - ID:Daniels-MacBook-Pro.local-56179-1359680042616-1:1:1 Transaction Commit :null
16:54:05,785 DEBUG [listenerContainer-1] ActiveMQSession:559 - ID:Daniels-MacBook-Pro.local-56179-1359680042616-1:1:1 Transaction Commit :null
16:54:06,787 DEBUG [listenerContainer-1] ActiveMQSession:559 - ID:Daniels-MacBook-Pro.local-56179-1359680042616-1:1:1 Transaction Commit :null
16:54:07,788 DEBUG [listenerContainer-1] ActiveMQSession:559 - ID:Daniels-MacBook-Pro.local-56179-1359680042616-1:1:1 Transaction Commit :null
...
```

FYI, I tried to turn off auto-startup (by setting `p:autoStartup="false"`) and manually start/stop the container in the code, but, it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

you shloud `stop()` the context before exiting:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException, InterruptedException  {
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("my-    context.xml");
    context.registerShutdownHook();

    App app = context.getBean("app", App.class);
    app.start();

    context.stop();
}
```

Comment: No, it didn't work. Also, I already called `context.registerShutdownHook()`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding `context.close()` call at the end.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("my-context.xml");
    context.registerShutdownHook();

    App app = context.getBean("app", App.class);
    app.start();

    context.close();
}
```

I left `context.registerShutdownHook()` call in case the app is closed externally (like `Ctrl+C`).

Am I doing it right?